# getting rid of unicode character 200F

Tags: unicode, characters

I typeset Arabic text with LuaLaTeX and recognised that quite often a character occurs in the resulting pdf that is invisible in the sourcetext -- it is unicode character `200f`: the right-to-left mark. I don't know why this character is printed in the output at all, but it is and it shouldn't be there.

Of course, I could delete all of them manually, but there are many of them and I fear that they will appear in the printed book.

The input is: `للشى
ء` (here on tex.sx it *is* visible, in TexShop it isn't).

The output is:

[image: the printed unicode character 200F]

So is there a way how I could just simply get rid of all of them? (search/replace doesn't work), i. a command I could add to the preamble without ruining anything else in my document?

This is a MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[36pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arabic Typesetting}
\newcommand{\arabtext}[1]   % Arabic inside LTR
    {\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}

\begin{document}
    \arabtext{للشى‏ء}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good question. You are right: RLM is a control character that can be necessary in bidirectional text but is not to be printed. A minimal example might help, as a solution *might* be specific to your setup. I don't know how necessary bidi controls are in the source to LuaLaTeX; it might be that the source doesn't require an RLM (but there is one in your source).

Comment: @Lover of Structure : I added a MWE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `\catcode` of the Right-to-Left Mark to 9, which will [make it ignored](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/catcode). The code for this is

```
\catcode"200F=9
```